# Eigenspace for the following matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We are given by a matrix
$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & A \\
A^T & 0
\end{array}\right]$ where $A$ is a real square matrix.

Is there a special name for this matrix?

I know that for an eigenpair $(\lambda,\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}\right])$ there is an eigenpair $(-\lambda,\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\
-y
\end{array}\right])$. Are there other spectral properties?

Comment: The most important thing is that this matrix is symmetric and its eigenvectors with nonnegative eigenvalues are "essentially" the singular vectors, i.e. they are of the form $\begin{bmatrix} v_i \\ u_i \end{bmatrix}$ (up to a constant factor of course). I've never heard a special name for it, though.

Comment: Right. Actually, I am considering of the relationship between right singular vectors and left singular vectors by observing this matrix. So, I am trying to being looking for if there is some research on this matrix.